# Android Testing - How to Synchronize AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, synchronization, testng

I am making a simple Venues application with the foursquare API. In the Activity I have a button that when clicked makes HTTP GET in AsyncTask to a service to take the trending venues around the user's current location. If the GET succeeds then a Fragment containing a ListView with the result is added to the activity.

I want to test if the Fragment is created after the button is clicked. The problem is that the AsyncTask is running in another thread and the test finishes with failed assertion.

**Here is the code:**

```
public void testBtnFindVenues_clickShouldInstantiateVenueListFragment() {
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, this.btnFindVenues);
    assertNotNull("VenueListFragment is null", this.getVenueListFragment());
}

private Fragment getVenueListFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.activity
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    VenueListFragment venueListFragment = (VenueListFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag(this.activity
                    .getString(R.string.fragment_tag_venue_list));

    return venueListFragment;
}
```

How can I make the assertion to be executed after the AsyncTask is executed

**EDIT: Here is the AsyncTask**

```
protected class HttpGetJsonTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponsePair> {
    private String requestUrl;
    private IOnSuccess onSuccess;
    private IOnError onError;

    public HttpGetJsonTask(String requestUrl) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
    }

    public void setOnSuccess(IOnSuccess onSuccess) {
        this.onSuccess = onSuccess;
    }

    public void setOnError(IOnError onError) {
        this.onError = onError;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponsePair doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(this.requestUrl);
        get.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        ResponsePair responsePair = new ResponsePair();

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            String jsonData = HttpRequester.this
                    .getResponseContentAsString(response);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            responsePair.setJsonData(jsonData);
            responsePair.setStatusCode(statusCode);

            return responsePair;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responsePair;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResponsePair responsePair) {
        super.onPostExecute(responsePair);

        HttpRequester.this.executeEvents(this.onSuccess, this.onError,
                responsePair);
    }
}

private void executeEvents(IOnSuccess onSuccess, IOnError onError,
        ResponsePair responsePair) {
    String jsonData = responsePair.getJsonData();
    int statusCode = responsePair.getStatusCode();

    if (statusCode / 100 == 4 || statusCode / 100 == 5 || statusCode == 0) {
        onError.performAction(jsonData);
    } else {
        onSuccess.performAction(jsonData);
    }
}

private String getResponseContentAsString(HttpResponse response) {
    String stringContent = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        StringBuilder stringContentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            stringContentBuilder.append(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        stringContent = stringContentBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return stringContent;
}
```

**Here is the setUp for the button and the transaction of the VenueListFragment**

```
private void setUpBtnFindVenues() {
    this.btnFindVenues = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_findVenues);
    this.btnFindVenues.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!NetworkUtils
                    .isNetworkConnectionEnabled(VenueListActivity.this)) {
                MessageNotifier.displayMessage(VenueListActivity.this,
                        R.string.toast_network_connection_not_found);

                return;
            }

            IOnSuccess onSuccess = new IOnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void performAction(String data) {
                    int index = data.indexOf("{\"venues\"");

                    data = data.substring(index, data.length() - 1);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    ResponseModel response = gson.fromJson(data,
                            ResponseModel.class);
                    VenueListActivity.this.venues = response.getVenues();

                    if (VenueListActivity.this.venues.size() == 0) {
                        MessageNotifier.displayMessage(
                                VenueListActivity.this,
                                R.string.toast_not_venues_within_radius);
                    }

                    VenueListActivity.this
                            .setUpVenueList(VenueListActivity.this.venues);
                }
            };

            IOnError onError = new IOnError() {
                @Override
                public void performAction(String data) {
                    MessageNotifier.displayMessage(VenueListActivity.this,
                            R.string.toast_problem_on_server);
                }
            };

            // Get the user's location
            Location location = VenueListActivity.this.locationTracker
                    .getLocation();

            if (location == null) {
                MessageNotifier.displayMessage(VenueListActivity.this,
                        R.string.toast_location_not_found);
            } else {
                // Build the route parameters HashMap
                Map<String, String> routeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                Log.d("denis", "Latitude: " + Double.toString(latitude));
                Log.d("denis", "Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
                routeParams.put("ll",
                        String.format("%s,%s", latitude, longitude));

                int radius = (VenueListActivity.this.seekBarRadius
                        .getProgress() + MIN_RADIUS) * SEEK_BAR_PROGRESS_MULTIPLIER;
                routeParams.put("radius", Integer.toString(radius));

                AppUtils.getData().venues()
                        .getTrendingVenues(routeParams, onSuccess, onError);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setUpVenueList(List<VenueModel> venues) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putBoolean(BundleKey.IS_TWO_PANE, this.isTwoPane);
    arguments.putString(BundleKey.VENUES, gson.toJson(venues));

    VenueListFragment fragment = new VenueListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_venueListContainer, fragment,
            this.getString(R.string.fragment_tag_venue_list));

    transaction.commit();
}
```

**Here is the method in the DataUnitOfWork**

```
public void getTrendingVenues(Map<String, String> routeParams,
        IOnSuccess onSuccess, IOnError onError) {
    if (!routeParams.containsKey("ll")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The routeParams Map does not contain the \"ll\" route parameter (it is required)");
    }

    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    urlBuilder.append(this.rootUrl);
    urlBuilder.append(String.format("%s%s", "trending", MainPersister.CLIENT_ROUTE_PARAMS));

    Set<String> keys = routeParams.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        urlBuilder.append(String.format("&%s=%s", key, routeParams.get(key)));
    }

    HttpGetJsonTask get = new HttpGetJsonTask(urlBuilder.toString());
    get.setOnSuccess(onSuccess);
    get.setOnError(onError);

    get.execute();
}
```

Comment: I do not know what do you need the assertion for. I am starting to get an impression that what you want to accomplish is more related to fragments life cycle more than it's to asynctask.

Comment: Well, is there a way to test the Fragment? I just want to test if the fragment is being added to the activity correctly.

Comment: You can take that for granted. When the activity creates the fragment and request to put it in a container you do not have to test if it succeeded. Inside the fragment to start populating data for example, put the code in onStart or onResume methods. This way it will start's its behavior when it's properly activated.

Comment: I see, so I don't need to test that out. Thanks mate. I will leave the question anyway so that actually someone has a solution regardless of that I don't need to test that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground` runs on another thread but `onPostExecute` runs on the calling thread.
Make sure the code which populates the UI after the `AsyncTask` is done is in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: I have an OnSuccess event handler which is executed in the onPostExecute(). The thing is that the test finishes before the onPostExecute() method is actually executed.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think that's all the code you need